# Calculating using SQL or C# - Multiple Columns & Rows

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table, and it has the Columns Quantity, Price and LineTotal. When I add something to the Cart, I add the Quantity and the Price of the product, and when the user visits the Cart page to view their cart, I want to re-calculate the LineTotal when they update the quantities for the items they've selected.

Now, my question is, should I re-calculate the LineTotal of each item in the cart using SQL (and if so, how?) or, should I do it in C# (And if so, what would be the best way to go about this?) To my surprise, I can't really seem to find anything on calculations in SQL - other than forums where people talk about it, but I have yet to see any code or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the arithmetic operators within SQL to generate your line totals.  Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187716.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you wanted to you could change the LineTotal column to a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) but there's nothing stopping you from doing it in C# before the Insert/update

Since it seems to be a fairly simple calculation its tough to really strongly go with one or the other, and its mostly up to preference

Computed Column sample

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD LineTotalComputed AS (Quantity * Price) PERSISTED
```